# Blank line after curly brace in function with uncrustify

Tags: uncrustify

I have configured xcode to use Uncrustify to beautify the code. I modified the Uncrustify configuration file and the resulting code is almost as desired.

One thing I don't like is the removal of a blank line between a closing curly brace and the next line of code. For example, this is what Uncrustify currently does:

Input:

```
if (jsonData != NULL)
{
    return [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
}

NSLog(@"Data read");
```

Current output:

```
if (jsonData != NULL)
{
    return [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
}
NSLog(@"Data read");
```

The desired output would be, in this case, the same as the input:

```
if (jsonData != NULL)
{
    return [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
}

NSLog(@"Data read");
```

I already played around with nl_after_func_body = true but this doesn't help.

---

I now managed to get the behaviour I wanted using the following addition to the configuration file:

```
nl_before_if = force
nl_after_if = force
nl_before_for = force
nl_after_for = force
nl_before_while = force
nl_after_while = force
nl_before_switch = force
nl_after_switch = force
nl_before_do = force
nl_after_do = force
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 nl_after_func_body = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
nl_after_if = add   # ignore/add/remove/force
```

In your config.

Inspired by: [Blank line after curly brace in function with uncrustify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163294/blank-line-after-curly-brace-in-function-with-uncrustify)