# Adding newline after if-else block using uncrustify

Tags: c++, uncrustify

Is there a way to introduce a new line after if-else block? Current code looks like this:

```
if (condition) {
}
else {
}
if (condition) {
}
statement;
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
if (condition) {
}
else {
}

if (condition) {
}

statement;
```

I have setup

> nl_after_if=force

but it doesn't seem to help.

EDIT: nl_after_if=force doesn't introduce a new line between to if blocks. The output is this:

```
if (condition) {
}
else {
}
if (condition) {
}

statement;
```

Which is potentially **more** confusing. Is there a way to solve this? I want a new line between multiple ifs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank line after curly brace in function with uncrustify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163294/blank-line-after-curly-brace-in-function-with-uncrustify)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option for that. However, maybe `nl_before_if` is close enough? (It will add the newline you are asking for in exactly your above example, at least.)

Although, it's not entirely obvious what `nl_after_if` is supposed to do. My guess from the documentation would be that it adds a newline `if (expr)<HERE>expr`, but it does seem to also add one between an `if`-chain and a following *non*-`if` statement, which seems inconsistent. In any case, you might want to consider [filling an issue](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues).